# How to find the explicit solution $y(x)$ in terms of a definite integral $\frac{dy}{dx} = (y(x^3+1))^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the difference between explicit and implicit solution?

I've already gotten as far as to separate the inequality 
$$\int_{9}^{y(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} dy=\int_{2}^{x}\sqrt{x^3+1}dx$$
I feel like this is wrong though

Comment: Hint: Can you compute the integrals on both sides?

Comment: Where do the limits on the integrals come from?  It is confusing to use the same variables inside the integral, where they are dummies, and in the limits, where they are real variables.

Comment: An explicit solution is a solution of the form $y(x) = ????$. In this case, the $????$ is going to have an integral in it, as the antiderivative of $\sqrt{1+x^3}$ is not a happy expression.

Comment: The RHS integral is non-elementary